# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error whenever I leave my drop down lists blank:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

My .aspx looks like below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboDay" runat="server" Width="55px" Height="32px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboMonth" runat="server" Width="80px" Height="30px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboYear" runat="server" Width="65px" Height="30px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("qryINSERTprof", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            String str = cboDay.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + cboMonth.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + cboYear.SelectedItem.Text;
            lbltxtage.Text = str;
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);

            string bdate = lbltxtage.Text;
            DateTime dts = DateTime.Parse(bdate);
            TimeSpan d = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dts);
            double years = d.TotalDays / 365;
            int months = (int)((years - (int)years) * 12);
            txtage.Text = ((int)years).ToString();

            Response.Write(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txtlname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname", txtmname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txtfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", lbltxtage.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtage.Text);

    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the string in question?

Comment: Way too much code and lacking formating. Your question is unreadable.

Comment: The `GetAge` method is setting my teeth on edge, too - once you've figured out your initial problem, it would be worth asking another question about that.

Comment: What is the value you have in `str` and does your current culture support that format

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy should be the format

Comment: @Photon that completely depends on the `Thread`s current culture.

Answer (score 3):

> I am getting this error whenever I leave my drop down lists blank

Then don't leave it blank, or change your code to detect empty input.

There are a few ways to do this, but for example you can do it like this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboDay.SelectedItem.Text)
        || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboMonth.SelectedItem.Text)
        || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboYear.SelectedItem.Text))
    {
        // TOOD: notify your UI that the values must be supplied
        return;
    }

    String str = cboDay.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + cboMonth.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + cboYear.SelectedItem.Text;
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I need to save values on my database even birthdate is not filled out by the user so I am allowing null on birth date that's why I did not set validation for not allowing blank on my ddl's.

Comment: @user2388316 then look at the magic of `if`. If no date has been entered, don't try to parse it and don't use it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Should you use a nullable datetime when the field is left blank?

```
DateTime? dt = null;
DateTime tmp;

if (DateTime.TryParse(
    String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 
        cboDay.SelectedItem.Text
        , cboMonth.SelectedItem.Text
        , cboYear.SelectedItem.Text
    )
    , out tmp
))
{
    dt = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using seperate dropdownlists for day month and year try this one

```
string date=cboDay.selectedtext+"/"+cbomonth.selectedtext+"/"+cboYear.selectedtext;
convert.todatetime(date);
```

but before trying this make sure that your day format is like 01,02,...29,30 and month format as 01,02,..11,12 all two digit format.otherwise you'll get an error.